# SAS PROC EXPORT to secure location

Tags: sas

I am trying to store a tabdelimited file to a shared folder that requires a login (username + password).

When I have opened (and logged in) to the location via windows explorer, `PROC EXPORT` runs without errors.

If I run it without having logged in during the windows session, I get a generic I/O error in the log.

Is there a way to add my login and password to the `PROC EXPORT` procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in [proc export](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003102702.htm) that will allow this.  I'd suggest running a windows command to open the share before the proc export, such as:

```
X "net use \\server\share /user:test /password:test"
```

or

```
filename mypipe pipe "net use \\server\share /user:test /password:test";
data _null_; infile mypipe; input; list; run;
filename mypipe close;
```

(credit - https://serverfault.com/questions/580369/windows-shares-via-command-line-with-user-pass-without-mapping-the-drive)

Comment: I get the following error with the 1st option: `ERROR: Shell escape is not valid in this SAS session.`

I get the following error with the 2nd option:
`ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access PIPE.
ERROR: Error in the FILENAME statement.`

Comment: Are you running this remotely in EG?  It sounds like you need to Allow XCMD in SMC (http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/allowing-xcmd-on-workspace-server.html)

Comment: I run this on EG 4.3 on a local server.

Comment: In that case you may need to update your registry to remove the `-NOXCMD` option on the startup of the local sas session.  Chris Hemedinger made a tool for this - see:  http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2009/11/19/using-the-x-and-systask-commands-from-sas-enterprise-guide/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I am doomed to use an overprotected workstation at my office. Registry changes or CMD prompt usage is not allowed.